# In R, how to return the name from columns A through E based on matching data in column in F?

Tags: r, matching

I want to return the column name from columns `A` through `E` based on matching data in column in `F`. I then want to return the value into a new column `G`.

For example:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(-0.113802816901408, -0.613802816901408, 
0.136197183098592, 0.126197183098592, 0.286197183098592), B = c(-0.294595070422536, 
-0.504595070422535, 0.125404929577464, 0.135404929577464, 0.275404929577465
), C = c(-0.277065727699531, -0.507065727699531, 0.282934272300469, 
0.0729342723004693, 0.122934272300469), D = c(-0.222699530516432, 
-0.132699530516432, -0.162699530516432, 0.127300469483568, -0.0126995305164321
), E = c(-0.246845657276995, -0.426845657276995, -0.186845657276995, 
0.133154342723005, 0.113154342723004), F = c(-0.222699530516432, 
-0.426845657276995, 0.136197183098592, 0.133154342723005, 0.275404929577465
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

So the vector for column `G` should end up being: `D`, `E`, `A`, `E`, `B`

Ideally, if there are multiple matches (which I don't think my example has), it would be good to send such information to a new column or perhaps to throw an error. This second issue is not as important though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the first 5 columns with `F` column and use `max.col` to get the column number with the same value.

```
df$G <- names(df)[max.col(df[1:5] == df$F)]
df

#           A          B           C           D          E          F G
#1 -0.1138028 -0.2945951 -0.27706573 -0.22269953 -0.2468457 -0.2226995 D
#2 -0.6138028 -0.5045951 -0.50706573 -0.13269953 -0.4268457 -0.4268457 E
#3  0.1361972  0.1254049  0.28293427 -0.16269953 -0.1868457  0.1361972 A
#4  0.1261972  0.1354049  0.07293427  0.12730047  0.1331543  0.1331543 E
#5  0.2861972  0.2754049  0.12293427 -0.01269953  0.1131543  0.2754049 B
```

In case of multiple matches `max.col` returns a random column number. You can handle it by specifying `ties.method`. See `?max.col` for more details.